# Blurry image after IFT using FFTW library in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, fftw

I have problem with image that I create using FFT and than IFFT. This is image that I'm converting: [oryginal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMeTw.png), and here is the one that i get after FFT and IFFT: [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUhEW.png). I assume that phase converting is fine, and the problem is somewhere in magnitude convertion. Below is part of my FFT function for red channel in loop for every pixel, outR is output from fftw_plan_dft_2d function and magRMax is maxiumum value of all magnitudes:

```
realR = outR[tempCounter][0] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);
imagR = outR[tempCounter][1] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);
...
magR = sqrt((realR * realR) + (imagR * imagR));
...
int param = 255;
magR = (param*log(magR+1)) / log(1 + magRMax);
...
magR = (magR > 255 ? 255 : magR);
...
magR = (magR < 0 ? 0 : magR);
...
tempColor.setRed((int)magR);
```

New pixels are assigned to magnitude image. After FFT and creating magnitude, phase images i'm trying to do IFFT without any midtime changes in magnitude, phase images. Below is part of my IFFT function for red chanell:

```
planR = fftw_plan_dft_2d(squareSize, squareSize, inR, outR, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
...
tempColor.setRgb(myImageMag->pixel(i,j));
tempColor2.setRgb(myImagePhase->pixel(i,j));

magR = tempColor.red() / 255.0;
phaseR = ((tempColor2.red() / 255.0) * 2 * M_PI) - M_PI;
inR[tempCounter][0] = (magR * cos(phaseR));
inR[tempCounter][1] = (magR * sin(phaseR));
...
redMax += abs(redMin);
...
red = (int)(outR[tempCounter][0]);
...
red = ((red + abs(redMin)) / (double)redMax)*255.0;
...
tempColor.setRed(red);
```

redMax is max value of all pixels of outR[tempCounter][0], redMin is min value of all pixel of outR[tempCounter][0]. redMax += abs(redMin) is scalling proces, because I get values below 0, also I scalled all reds values.

Code to program on GitHub:

```
https://github.com/Hariver/POID/blob/master/main.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Blurry pixels simply mean that each pixel is smeared out in the spatial domain (a convolution). Convolutions in the spatial domain are multiplications in the frequency domain, which indeed appears to be what you're doing.